# BibTeX entry for an ever-changing document

Tags: bibtex

I want to cite a program documentation that has a new release every year.

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{FoobarReference,
  author = {Smart Guy},
  title = {The Foo/Bar Reference Manual},
  booktitle = {},
  year = {1999},
  publisher = {}
}
```

Is it enough to change the year for that, or what is expected from a learned scholar? This documentation exists only in pdf, it is not published and printed.

Comment: For a start I'd use `@manual`.  From the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Standard_templates): "Technical manual

    Required fields: title.
    Optional fields: author, organization, address, edition, month, year, note."  The required fields are more appropriate.  Alternatively if you use `@misc` there's the `howpublished` field to allow you to put the URL in the bibliography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a macro in the `year` field, which you set in the document.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@manual{FoobarReference,
  author = {Smart Guy},
  title = {The Foo/Bar Reference Manual},
  year = {\foobaryear},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foobaryear}{2015}

\begin{document}

The manual is \cite{FoobarReference}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Thus you don't need to modify the `.bib` file. Note that the `@inproceedings` type is not appropriate for this kind of reference: choose either `@manual` or `@book`.

Note that the `filecontents*` environment is just to keep the example self-contained, you'll use the standard method with a separate `.bib` file.

[image]

If you are using `natbib`, a hack is necessary:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@manual{FoobarReference,
  author = {Smart Guy},
  title = {The Foo/Bar Reference Manual},
  year = {\foobaryear},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\newcommand{\foobaryear}{2015}

\let\oribibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem[#1(#2)]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\oribibitem[\unexpanded{#1}(#2)]%
  }\x
}


\begin{document}
The manual is \cite{FoobarReference}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```